# Php and Jquery, How do i post a option selected value into a span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to post a value of a selected option into a span/label without submit button?, how do I do that?
I've already did it with a input text box but with a selection option I just can't...

Here's my actual code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function calculateTotal() {

    var totalAmt = document.addem.total.value;
    totalR = eval(document.addem.tb1.value * 0.8);

    document.getElementById('update').innerHTML = totalR;
}

  </script>
  <div id="swag">   
  <form name="addem" id="addem">
  <select name="simulate_option" id="simulate_opt">
   <option value="EUR" selected="selected">EUR</option>
    <option value="USD">USD</option>
    <option value="CHF">CHF</option>
    <option value="GBP">GBP</option>
    <option value="RON">RON</option>
    <option value="CZK">CZK</option>
    <option value="NOK">NOK</option>
    <option value="DKK">DKK</option>
    <option value="LVL">LVL</option>
    <option value="TRY">TRY</option>
    <option value="HRK">HRK</option>
    <option value="SEK">SEK</option>
    <option value="PLN">PLN</option>
    <option value="HUF">HUF</option>
    <option value="MXN">MXN</option>
    <option value="CAD">CAD</option>
    </select>   
<input type="text" name="tb1" onkeyup="calculateTotal()"/>   
<span class="swag" id="update">0</span>
<input type="hidden" name="total" value="0"/>
     </form>
```

Comment: There is thing called jquery...

Comment: You've got a few options. If you don't want to do this on submit, then on what event do you actually want to post back to the server?

Comment: Yes but what code :/? can you post it?

Comment: This isn't a code mill. What have you tried and what didn't work?

Comment: When the user selects the type of currency, it updates automaticly that value to the value of a span or label

Comment: I've tried many Jquery codes, like a 4 of them..

Comment: in jquery parlance, `document.getElementById('update')` may be replaced by `$('#update')`. If you know a little CSS, you'll pick it up quickly, and find it much easier to use than the default javascript API. You should try to reformulate your code using that first, then try to describe "formally" step by step what you wish to accomplish. Once you've got that, try to translate each step into a line of code. If you get stuck after that on an error, come back and ask.

Comment: But it works this way o.O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this piece of javascript code should help.

```
//runs when a value is changed in the combobox.
var dropdown = document.getElementById("simulate_opt");
dropdown.onchange = function(event){
    //loads data from combobox.
    var val = dropdownoptions[simulate_opt.slectedIndex].value;
    //CHANGE THESE 2 strings.
    Ajax("id of div to be changed", "url to the php file", array(val));
}

//A basic dynamic javascript function for AJAX
//div is div to be changed, url = url to php file.
//vars = array with items to be send via Post
function Ajax(div, url, vars){
    var xml = new XMLHttpRequest(); //wont work in ie7 or lower
    xml.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(xml.readyState==4 && xml.status==200){
            document.getElementById(div).innerHTML=xml.responseText;
        }
    };
    xml.open("POST",URL,true);
    xml.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    sendXML(xml, vars);
}

function sendXML(xml, vars){
    var send = "";
    var i = 1;
    for(var x in vars){
        y = vars[x];
        send = send+"&var"+i+"="+y;
        i++;
    }
    xml.send(send);
}
```

Then have a php file like this.

```
<?php
$var = $_POST['var1'] //loads the selected value
echo $var;  //shows selected value.
?>
```

The Ajax function can be used to realtime update the page without need for refreshing. 
it calls to a php script which then can modify a div with `echo`. give the Ajax function the ID of a div that will be changed by php, the url to php and put any variables php needs from the client in an array as the third variable.

```
//for instance
Ajax("header", "loadHeader.php", Array("hello"."world");
//In php the array items are obtainable as follows.
$_POST['var1']; // this is "hello"
$_POST['var2']; // this is "world"
//if any more array items were added they would've been.
$_POST['var3']; //etc for as much as were set.
```

Comment: It's a jQuery question, so this should be in a jQuery format. Additionally, it's leaving out the AJAX portions of the requirement.

Comment: even if you have jquery is it fobidden to use normal javascript for something as simple as this?

Comment: I strongly recommend against it, especially in the context of this question where the OP wants to use jQuery.

Comment: besides the tags I havent seen him specify jquery

Comment: tbh, OP doesn't use either PHP or JQuery in his question, yet he tagged it as such, perhaps it was mistake from his part?

Comment: Good point, perhaps he's misunderstood the difference between JavaScript and jQuery

Comment: if you want to do it better with jquery go ahead post a better answer

Comment: Yes, that's the code, (I haven't learned any Jquery yet...) what code can I put there to change the value of <span id="update2"><span/>
??????

Comment: working on it, but you need ajax, I got some working ajax version without jquery.

Comment: Yes I the tags are wrong sorry, I thought Jquery might be the solution to this problem...

Comment: Thanks @kpp :DDDDDDDDDDDDDDD

Comment: changed it, ill be gone now back later

Comment: Thanks!, so i just put that code inside 
<script type="text/javascript">
//code
</script>

right? and then I create the php file and then I require the php file into the index.html and then I've got the value of the combobox right?

Comment: if you put the javascript in between script tags then it should work, you only need to edit the 2 vars between `"div"` in the first function. there isnt even need to include the php-file then